# Selenium Webdriver - Validate a value in tooltip for a section (bar) of a bar chart

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to validate the value of the margin (sum) element from the bar chart as shown below. So how do I extract the value 31732 from margin (sum) tooltip for Electrolux vendor (bar 1) in the bar chart?

[image: Bar chart tool tip]

The html for the div enclosing this value is also given below.

I would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="highcharts-60" class="highcharts-container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 727px; height: 378px; text-align: left; font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; left: 0px; top: -0.600006px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="727" height="378">
<defs>
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="#FFFFFF" x="0" y="0" width="727" height="378" stroke-width="0" stroke="#4572A7">
<text class="highcharts-title" x="364" y="25" style="font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10px;color:#3E576F;fill:#3E576F;" text-anchor="middle" zIndex="1">
<g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1">
<g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1">
<path d="M 106.5 40 L 106.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 147.5 40 L 147.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 187.5 40 L 187.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 228.5 40 L 228.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 269.5 40 L 269.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 310.5 40 L 310.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 350.5 40 L 350.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 391.5 40 L 391.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 432.5 40 L 432.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 473.5 40 L 473.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 513.5 40 L 513.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 554.5 40 L 554.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 595.5 40 L 595.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 636.5 40 L 636.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 676.5 40 L 676.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M 717.5 40 L 717.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1">
</g>
<g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3">
<g class="highcharts-series" width="611" height="251" transform="translate(717,291) rotate(90) scale(-1,1)" clip-path="url(https://staging.datarpm.com/analytics/4fbf89e5e4b0a97336652433#highcharts-61)" visibility="visible">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="220.5" y="352.5" width="18" height="258" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="220.5" y="352.5" width="18" height="258" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="220.5" y="352.5" width="18" height="258" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#4572A7" x="220.5" y="352.5" width="18" height="258" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0" fill-opacity="1">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="178.5" y="319.5" width="18" height="291" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="178.5" y="319.5" width="18" height="291" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="178.5" y="319.5" width="18" height="291" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#4572A7" x="178.5" y="319.5" width="18" height="291" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0" fill-opacity="1">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="136.5" y="293.5" width="18" height="317" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="136.5" y="293.5" width="18" height="317" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="136.5" y="293.5" width="18" height="317" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#4572A7" x="136.5" y="293.5" width="18" height="317" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0" fill-opacity="1">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="94.5" y="62.5" width="18" height="548" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="94.5" y="62.5" width="18" height="548" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="94.5" y="62.5" width="18" height="548" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#4572A7" x="94.5" y="62.5" width="18" height="548" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="52.5" y="257.5" width="18" height="353" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="52.5" y="257.5" width="18" height="353" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="52.5" y="257.5" width="18" height="353" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#4572A7" x="52.5" y="257.5" width="18" height="353" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="10.5" y="247.5" width="18" height="363" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="10.5" y="247.5" width="18" height="363" stroke-width="3" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="10.5" y="247.5" width="18" height="363" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" r="0" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(-1,-1)">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#4572A7" x="10.5" y="247.5" width="18" height="363" stroke-width="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0">
</g>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(298,337)">
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="130" height="25" stroke-width="1" stroke="#909090" visibility="visible">
<text x="30" y="18" style="font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#3E576F;fill:#3E576F;" zIndex="2">
<tspan x="30"> margin (sum)</tspan>
</text>
<rect rx="2" ry="2" fill="#4572A7" x="9.5" y="7.5" width="16" height="12" stroke-width="1" zIndex="3" stroke="#FFFFFF" r="0">
</g>
<g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="7">
<text x="26" y="165.5" style="font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#6D869F;font-weight:bold;fill:#6D869F;" zIndex="7" transform="rotate(270 26 165)" text-anchor="middle">
<g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="7">
<text x="411.5" y="323" style="font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#6D869F;font-weight:bold;fill:#6D869F;" zIndex="7" text-anchor="middle">
<tspan x="411.5"> margin (sum)</tspan>
</text>
<path d="M 106.5 40 L 106.5 291" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1" zIndex="7">
<g class="highcharts-tooltip" zIndex="8" visibility="hidden" transform="translate(202.5577832333554,26.04093567342961)">
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="7" y="7" width="131" height="38" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0.85" isShadow="true" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(1,1)">
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="7" y="7" width="131" height="38" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity="0.85" isShadow="true" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(1,1)">
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="7" y="7" width="131" height="38" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.85" isShadow="true" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(1,1)">
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="7" y="7" width="131" height="38" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.85" stroke="#4572A7">
<text x="12" y="24" style="font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333333;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;fill:#333333;" zIndex="1">
<tspan style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;" x="12">Electrolux</tspan>
<tspan style="font-weight:bold" dy="13" x="12"> margin (sum)</tspan>
<tspan dx="3"> : 31732</tspan>
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-tracker" zIndex="9" transform="translate(717,291) rotate(90) scale(-1,1)" width="611" height="251">
<rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="url(https://staging.datarpm.com/analytics/4fbf89e5e4b0a97336652433#highcharts-62)" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="23" height="19" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(693,348)" zIndex="19" stroke="#B0B0B0">
<rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="url(https://staging.datarpm.com/analytics/4fbf89e5e4b0a97336652433#highcharts-63)" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="23" height="19" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(693,328)" zIndex="19" stroke="#B0B0B0">
<path d="M 6 17 L 18 17 18 14 6 14 Z M 12 14 L 9 9 11 9 11 5 13 5 13 9 15 9 Z" fill="#A8BF77" transform="translate(693,348)" stroke="#A0A0A0" stroke-width="1" zIndex="20">
<path d="M 6 14 L 18 14 18 9 6 9 Z M 9 9 L 9 5 15 5 15 9 Z M 9 14 L 7.5 17 16.5 17 15 14 Z" fill="#B5C9DF" transform="translate(693,328)" stroke="#A0A0A0" stroke-width="1" zIndex="20">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="693" y="348" width="24" height="20" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.001" title="Export to raster or vector image" zIndex="21" style="cursor:pointer;">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="693" y="328" width="24" height="20" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.001" title="Print the chart" zIndex="21" style="cursor:pointer;">
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you control the highcharts code?  If so it would be easier to test that directly within the tooltip data that you're passing it rather than trying to pull it from the SVG.

Comment: No, I don't. There is another team that handle dev for the project.

Comment: ok.  Still might be easier to extact the Javascript highcharts object and test that rather than trying to pull from the SVG. There will be some sort of Highcharts/Highstock object accessible to you as well as the SVG.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example of the same or point me someplace where I can find more information?

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/ would be a place to start.  I don't know enough about your set up to say how the highcharts object would be saved/accessible.  I suggest talking with the dev team about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that are not testing the `highcharts` themselves, but only that the correct data is passed to it. Since testing whether the data is visualized correctly would be `highcharts`'s responsibility.

If in JavaScript chart has been assign to a variable (e.g. `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ ... })`), then you can try to get the data by calling the [highcharts series data api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.data)

```
int[] data = js.executeScript("return chart.series.data;");
```

If that doesn't work, then you can always extract the data from the html like this:

```
//get the element that contains the data
WebElement currentValueElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@class="highcharts-tooltip"]//text/tspan[last()]'));

//get the value from that element
int currentvalue = Integer.parseInt(currentValueElement.split(":")[1].trim())
```

Comment: Thanks much, I used this tip and got it working by directly manipulating the div under the svg tag.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the tooltip might be a dynamic Javascript popup like  you see with some dropdown menus such as Google search tips.  You are the only person to have access to the FULL source (HTML headers) and so only you can figure that out for us.   That being the case, if you are desparate, you can use a physical mouse click (using Webdriver Action class) combined with a slight delay and some keystrokes to select and copy (with ctrl-c )  and then access the clipboard with java.awt.Toolkit  to get the value and then process it.  This is just off the top of my head.

There may be better ways of doing this than what I suggest above.   Alternatively, it's very possible that the DOM has access to the values of that tooltip (where you can use a cssSelector to get) but without having access to you page with Firebug (using Firefinder plugin), its hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using this xpath and getting text from it?

```
"//tspan[@dx='3']"
```